# C# Activator.GetInstance instances don't retain state when created as Interfaces

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to find all instances of `ICollector` and instantiate each using this code block

```
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICollector))
                      && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ICollector;
```

The instances are created just fine, but when I call the method `Start()` on each instance (which is part of the interface), then properties set inside the method lose their value once the method is exited.

For example an instance of `ICollector` is `NetworkCollector` and it has this code in the `Start()` method

```
instanceNames = networkCategory.GetInstanceNames().ToList();
currentActivity = new List<CounterValues>();
counters = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
```

And those variables are also populated with actual values. When I subsequently call those variables in the `Collect()` method (also part of the interface `ICollector`) they are all null.

Am I missing something, or are these instances losing state?

Comment: We need more context. Are there any other operations going on? Perhaps you're not using the same instance as the one you're populating?

Comment: Does it work if you create the objects by hand? i.e. if you just do a `var thing = new SpecificCollectorClass();` and then call the `Start()` method are the values retained?

Comment: I do hope you are using `class` and not `struct` for the types that implement `ICollector`

Comment: if you are doing something like `foreach(ICollector c in instances) c.Start();` ... `foreach(ICollector c in instances) c.Collect();`, you enumerate instances source twice. make a permanent source: `var instancesList = instances.ToList();foreach(ICollector c in instancesList) c.Start();`...`foreach(ICollector c in instancesList) c.Collect();`

Comment: Yes, if I do it by hand it works just fine. I am attempting to generalise the construction of the objects as there will be an indeterminate number of them.

Comment: It was indeed multiple enumeration that was the problem. Adding a `ToList()` before using the instances fixed it. Thanks to all.